# Cannot skip youtube ad

Tags: javascript, html, node.js, puppeteer

I'm trying to test to see if I can skip the ad on youtube using nodejs puppeteer.
This is just testing purposes, but it's not working when it should be.

I put it in a while loop to find if it can be skipped, then click the class element. Though it's not doing anything, and it just doesn't work. This code is also in another async function by the way.

**edited with help from @sharmila:**

```
          const waitForAdSkip = async () => {
            const skipButtonSelectors = ['#ad-text\\:7', '#ad-text\\:6'];

            while (true) {
              let isSkippable = false;
              for (const selector of skipButtonSelectors) {
                const skipButton = await videoPage.$(selector);
                if (skipButton) {
                  const isHidden = await skipButton.evaluate((el) => el.offsetParent === null);
                  const isDisabled = await skipButton.evaluate((el) => el.disabled);
                  if (!isHidden && !isDisabled) {
                    console.log('Ad is skippable. Skipping...');
                    await skipButton.click();
                    isSkippable = true;
                    break;
                  }
                }
              }

              if (isSkippable) {
                break;
              }

              console.log('Ad is not skippable yet. Waiting...');
              await videoPage.waitForTimeout(2000);
            }
          };

          await waitForAdSkip();

          console.log('Ad skipped. Continuing with the rest of the script...');
          await videoPage.waitForTimeout(30000);
```

**Old code before edit**:

```
const waitForAdSkip = async () => {
            while (true) {
              const skipButton = await videoPage.$('.ytp-ad-skip-button');
              if (skipButton) {
                console.log('Ad is skippable. Skipping...');
                // Check if the button is clickable
                const isClickable = await skipButton.isIntersectingViewport();
                if (isClickable) {
                  // Perform any desired action to skip the ad, like clicking the skip button.
                  await skipButton.click();
                  break;
                }
              }
              console.log('Ad is not skippable yet. Waiting...');
              // Wait for a few seconds before checking again.
              await videoPage.waitForTimeout(2000);
            }
          };

          // Wait for the "Skip Ad" button to appear and be clickable
          await waitForAdSkip();

          // Continue with the rest of your code after the ad is skipped
          console.log('Ad skipped. Continuing with the rest of the script...');

          // Wait for the rest of the code to execute
          await videoPage.waitForTimeout(30000);
```

I was expecting it to skip the ad when the text of the element contains "Skip Ad" and then break the loop and click on skip ad.

Comment: JavaScript is single-threaded.  So if your while loop is still running, none of the async tasks created within it are able to start.

Comment: @James  while loops will work fine with `async / await`..

Answer (score 0):

here's an updated code:

```
const waitForAdSkip = async () => {
  while (true) {
    const skipButton = await videoPage.$('.ytp-ad-skip-button');
    if (skipButton) {
      const isHidden = await skipButton.evaluate((el) => el.offsetParent === null);
      const isDisabled = await skipButton.evaluate((el) => el.disabled);
      if (!isHidden && !isDisabled) {
        console.log('Ad is skippable. Skipping...');
        await skipButton.click();
        break;
      }
    }
    console.log('Ad is not skippable yet. Waiting...');
    await videoPage.waitForTimeout(2000);
  }
};

await waitForAdSkip();

console.log('Ad skipped. Continuing with the rest of the script...');

await videoPage.waitForTimeout(30000);
```